# MySQL increment a row value once a day on that day then reset if next day

Tags: php, mysql

I am coding a new project and want to make my database row value `traffic` increment once if it ran on that day, `07-03-2019` for example, then reset back to 0 once next day hits and it is executed. Is there any easy way to do this?

Take a look at my code.

I have been Googling for days, and every time it rolls over to the next day, it increments traffics current value on top of the yesterday value, not resetting back to zero.

```
//Current date
$date = date("Y-m-d");
$sqlQuery ="
    UPDATE users 
    SET traffic = traffic + 1
    WHERE datestamp = '$date'";
    $result = $conn->query($sqlQuery );
```

I expect traffic to increment by 1 if executed on today's date, then if not on today, go to zero for the next day.

How do I make it reset back to 0 on the next day? I don't know where to start. Increment works, not reset.

Comment: I see where it's incrementing, but where is it setting to 0?

Comment: that's the thing, I don't know where to add the code to reset `traffic` value back to zero if `$date` is `07-04-2019`. I need to know how to do that.

Comment: Why do you need to reset the traffic for the next day? How did it get incremented in the first place?

Comment: I am using Google Charts, it is essentially being used for statistics.

Comment: Still don't understand. How are you getting statistics for future dates that need to be set back to 0?

Comment: And why only set tomorrow's traffic to 0, not all future dates?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `CASE` expression to calculate the value:

```
UPDATE users
SET traffic = CASE datestamp
        WHEN CURDATE() THEN traffic + 1
        ELSE 0
    END
WHERE datestamp IN (CURDATE(), DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

So if you run this on 2019-07-03, it will increment the traffic for that date, and set the traffic for 2019-07-04 to 0. When you run it on 2019-07-04, it will increment that date, and set 2019-07-05 to 0.

Comment: Excellent looking answer. Let me try it and get to you with any concerns.